# Undefined index after json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a problem when I'm trying to get the contents of a JavaScript Array and pass its value to a PHP Array Variable.

What I'm doing is that, when a user clicks a button, the value of the item clicked will be added to the javascript array and every time the javascript array updates, the PHP variable will also update and so the contents of the div displaying the contents of the PHP array. I'm not using forms for this matter but buttons

However, when I try to use the `json_decode` function to get the values of a JavaScript array, it's giving me a `Message: undefined index: data` error

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX so please bear with me

This is my code:

```
<script>
    // ARRAY VARIABLE WHERE ITEM VALUES WILL BE STORED
    var food_item = new Array();

    // FUNCTION TO BE TRIGGERED WHEN USER CLICKED THE BUTTON, GET THE ITEM'S VALUE AND ADD IT TO ARRAY
    function addToTray(data){
        food_item.push(document.getElementById(data).value);
        dataString = food_item; // array?
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "main",
                data: {data: jsonString}, 
                cache: false,

                success: function(){
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });
    }
</script>

<body>
    ...

    // LINE OF CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR FETCHING JAVASCRIPT ARRAY VALUES
    $this->session->userdata['food_tray'] = json_decode($_POST['data']);

    // DIV TO BE UPDATED

    <div class="col-md-3 food-tray" id="food-items" style="margin-top: 7%">
        <!--FOOD TRAY-->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="ft-header">Food Tray</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
                $count_fi = count($this->session->userdata('food_tray'));

                echo "<p>Your Items (" . $count_fi . ")</p>";

                if($count_fi == 0){
                    echo "<p class='no-avail-list'>NO ITEMS ADDED IN FOOD TRAY</p>";
                }else{
                    echo "<table class='table borderless'>";

                    for($i = 0; $i < $count_fi; $i++){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $this->session->userdata['food_tray'][$i] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>P 200.00</td>";
                        echo "<td><form method='post'><input type='number' name='qty' min='1' max='100' value='1'/></form></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "<a href='' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                        Add Friend</a>";
                    echo "<a href='".base_url()."index.php/CheckOut' class='btn btn-warning'>Proceed to Checkout</a>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

    <?php
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            echo "<div class='col-lg-7'>";
                echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
                    $file_name = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-.]/', '', $row->name));
                    /*if(file_exists(FCPATH . '/assets/images/main/food/' . $file_name . '.jpg')){
                        echo "<img src='".base_url()."/assets/images/main/food/".$file_name.".jpg' alt='' width='320px' height='100px'>";
                      }else{
                        echo "<img src='http://placehold.it/320x150' alt=''>";
                      }*/
                      echo "<img src='http://placehold.it/320x150' alt=''>";
                      echo "<div class='caption'>";
                        echo "<h5 class='pull-right'>&#x20B1 " . $row->price . "</h5>";
                        echo "<h5><a href='#'>" . $row->name . "</a></h5>";
                        echo "<h5>Calorie Count :  " . ($row->calorie_count == NULL ? "Not Available" : $row->calorie_count) . "</h5>";
                        // BUTTON FOR `addToTray()` FUNCTION
                        echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' id='".$row->id."' value='".$row->name."' style='width:100%' onclick='addToTray(".$row->id.")'>Add to Tray</button>";
                        // var_dump($row->name);
                      echo "</div>";
               echo "</div>";
           echo "</div>";
       }
    ?>
</body>
```

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions**; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152167/discussion-on-question-by-chamber-undefined-index-after-json-decode). If prompted for clarification or code, it should be [edit]ed into your question. If you have now solved the problem, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

create your session as

```
$array = array ('food_tray' => json_decode($javascriptarray));
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

check if your javascript libraries are loaded in sources tab.